# How to Unearth the Buried Regression Line in GGPLOT

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Currently my regression plot looks like this. Notice that 
the regression line is deeply buried.

Is there any way I can modify my code here, to show it on top of the dots?
I know I can increase the size but it's still underneath the dots.

```
p <- ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=x,y=y),) +
     xlab("x") +
     ylab("y")+
     geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color="red",formula=y~x,size=1.5) +
     geom_point()
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change the order:

```
p <- ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=x,y=y),) +
     xlab("x") +
     ylab("y")+
     geom_point() +
     geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color="red",formula=y~x,size=1.5)
p
```

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - I don't understand - I haven't changed color, all I've done is swap the order between geom_point() and geom_smooth()... which is the same as the answer you gave!

Comment: I'm very sorry.  I missread the word "order" as "color".  I think that means it is time for me to get some sleep :)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not the color, but the **order** of the geoms. 
If you first call `geom_point()` and *then* `geom_smooth()`
the latter will be on top of the former.

Plot the following for comparison:

```
Before <- 
  ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=x,y=y),) +
     xlab("x") +
     ylab("y")+
     geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color="red",formula=y~x,size=1.5) +
     geom_point()

After <- 
  ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=x,y=y),) +
     xlab("x") +
     ylab("y")+
     geom_point() + 
     geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color="red",formula=y~x,size=1.5)
```

---

[image: Line Plotted AFTER Points]

[image: Line Plotted BEFORE Points]

Answer (score 2):

How about transparent points?

```
library(ggplot2)
seed=616
x1<- sort(runif(rnorm(1000)))
seed=626
x2<- rnorm(1000)*0.02+sort(runif(rnorm(1000)))
my_df<- data.frame(x= x1, y = x2)
p <- ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=x,y=y),) +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y")+ 
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,color="red",formula=y~x,size=1.5)+
  geom_point(size = I(2), alpha = I(0.1))
p
```

[image: Transparent plot points]